# Unable to enqueue core wordpress scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have my wordpress functions in the object orientated style of classes, I have used this method to enqueue a few scripts, the core jquery script and some custom scripts. They all work as expected, and they all follow this method of enqueue.

```
function lart_front_end_scripts() {
        if (is_admin()) return;
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', '1.10.2' );
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('underscore');
        wp_enqueue_script('mainJS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mainJS.js', array("jquery", "wp-ajax-response") );
        }//End add_scripts

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this,'lart_front_end_scripts'));
```

Looking at my console I can see jquery and mainJS have loaded but both underscore and masonry have not. (Note: I had to use a cdn to get Underscore to work just to code some stuff)

What could be stopping masonry and underscore from being loaded?

Comment: Have you registered the script prior to enqueuing...

Comment: I didn't think you had to register core wordpress scripts, just enqueue them?

Comment: yeah you are right... I missed on these being the core WP scripts

Comment: But for some reason Jquery is a core script but still loads. It's weird.

Comment: jquery-masonry has jquery as the dependency .. Can u add it in the code and check if it works

Comment: Ah yes, I had that in there before but took it out when I was looking for the bug, still doesn't work. I should also mention that I'm developing locally on ubuntu, so perhaps file permissions could be the problem?

Comment: Yes totally that can be an issue ... I face permission issues a lot as i use ubuntu too... and keep scratching my head until i see the file permisssion ;)

Comment: I just chmod' 777 my wp-includes folder... still nothing. Sigh.

Comment: dependency is the third parameter, not the second

Comment: @MarutiMohanty, maybe you should add this as an answer? I think it solves the Q.

Comment: yes i think this should solve. Lets wait for @KyleJoseph to reply :)

Comment: So you mean something like `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry', FALSE, array('jquery'));`? Nope.